# Is a good practice to use static variables for holding properties from file in a Spring MVC project

Tags: java, spring, variables, spring-mvc, properties

The code below is working perfectly but I am in doubt if I am using the best approach for the requirenment: read, from a couple of places, property from a properties file in a Spring project. Basically, I created a public class with static variables. Now I am using Spring 3 plus JDK6. I might upgrade Spring to 4 soon but I will not be able to chnage JDK version.

mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Properties File

```
url = http://localhost:8080/MHE2/
lastpage = log/display/last
firstpage = log/display/first
previouspage = log/display/previous
nextpage = log/display/next
```

One sample of using the property value. There will be a lot of case like these

```
             //calling rest web service
             DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  //Apache HttpClient
             HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(Ut_Properties.getUrl() + Ut_Properties.getLastpage());
```

Public class with static variables

```
package com.mastercard.mhe.utilities;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("ut_Properties")
@Scope("singleton")
public class Ut_Properties {

       private static String url;
       private static String lastpage;
       private static String firstpage;
       private static String previouspage;
       private static String nextpage;

    @Autowired
    public Ut_Properties(@Value("${url}") String url,
              @Value("${lastpage}") String lastpage,
              @Value("${url}") String previouspage,
              @Value("${lastpage}") String nextpage) {

       Ut_Properties.setUrl(url);
       Ut_Properties.setLastpage(lastpage);
       Ut_Properties.setUrl(previouspage);
       Ut_Properties.setLastpage(nextpage);

    }



       public static String getUrl() {

              return url;

       }



       public static void setUrl(String url) {

              Ut_Properties.url = url;

       }



       public static String getFirstpage() {

              return firstpage;

       }



       public static void setFirstpage(String firstpage) {

              Ut_Properties.firstpage = firstpage;

       }



       public static String getPreviouspage() {

              return previouspage;

       }



       public static void setPreviouspage(String previouspage) {

              Ut_Properties.previouspage = previouspage;

       }



       public static String getNextpage() {

              return nextpage;

       }



       public static void setNextpage(String nextpage) {

              Ut_Properties.nextpage = nextpage;

       }



      public static String getLastpage() {

              return lastpage;

       }



       public static void setLastpage(String lastpage) {

              Ut_Properties.lastpage = lastpage;

       }

}
```

Comment: The question you should ask yourself is, is this easy to test?

Comment: Firstly, thank you. It seems that you are giving me some insight about difficult to use JUnit. Can you please go depper in your suggestion? What is the proble with this approach for testing purpose or TDD or BBD? I can answer that it is easy to test because I only have to look in the variable if it holds the value but I can see that you are giving me some importante light that I didn't pick up entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
@Service
public class MyPropertiesServ implements InitializingBean {

@Autowired
protected ApplicationContext context;
private Properties properties;

private static MyPropertiesServ singleInst;

protected MyPropertiesServ () {
    properties = new Properties();
    singleInst= this;
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    properties.load(context.getResource("classpath:file.properties").getInputStream());
}

public static String getStringProperty(String key) {
    return singleInst.properties.getProperty(key);
}

}
```

Another example:
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/35703-initialising-static-property-of-class-through-injection-on-startup

Comment: I can see that instead of creating a Singleton component with static variables, you seem to prefer create a Service component and create a Static object of this class. Is there advantage in this approach? Eg. is it easy for testing? I am still didn't find problem to use the way I created and I didn't see a reasonable better way. My wonderying is that I build this solution based on my limited knowledge of Spring and you can note that I did as a very old fashion way: a singleton with static variables and initializing the properties through contexto:property-placeholder so I can reach the values.

Answer (score 0):

`@Value` is a lovely annotation but looking at your code I'm wondering if it is important for you that those variables representing the properties are static ? 
If not you could avoid alot of `clutter code` by not making them static.

```
@Component
public class Ut_Properties {

   @Value("${url}")
   private String url;
   // ...
   public getUrl() { return url; }

@Component/Service/Controller
public class ClassFromWhereYouWantToAccessTheProperties {

    @Inject
    Ut_Properties utProperties;
    // you could ofcourse just inject the properties in the classes where you need them instead of trying to gather them in one class.
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url; 

    public void someRandomMethod() {
        utProperties.getUrl();
        // vs
        this.url;
```

Comment: I don't think your idea will even been compiled. First, can I really have @Value("${someThingFromPropertyFile}") above static variable? My requirenment is to be able to read the value from any place in my code, so the variable has to been accessible from all code. As far as I remenber I can't compile @Value("$...") above static variable as I can with @Value("#...") above a setMethod setting a static variable. Second, the only significant difference in your suggestion is the getMethod (getUrl) not been static. If I didn't understand your suggestion properly, please correct me.

Comment: Indeed, my mistake. Should have been an instance variable not static, sorry!

Comment: Corrected my answer so it makes more sense.

Comment: Thanks. Let's say that I want to use the "this.url" alternative. Does it really work in all context? Kindly look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070823/value-not-working-inside-a-class-which-extends-other. I try hard similiar approach but it only works when postConstruct event is triggered. Is your solution below really possible to make work without static object? If so, do I have to add extra configuration in somewhere?
@Component
public class ClassFromWhereYouWantToAccessTheProperties {
@Value("${url}")
private String url; 
 public void someRandomMethod() {
 this.url

Comment: in case you didn't understand my question, please, let me know.